# How to indexes ImageField in django-elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

Рello everyone! I am writing a site on Django. I am making a search system using  `django-elasticsearch-dsl`.
And I have a problem when I need to index an **ImageField** field in the **BookDocument** class in order to display a book image on the book search page

Here is my Book model:

***books/models.py***

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, default=' ', verbose_name='Назва')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Опис')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категорія')
    date_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата створення')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, verbose_name='Автори')
    content = models.FileField(upload_to='contents/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Ціна', default='0')
```

Here is my BookDocument class:

***search/documents.py***

```
@registry.register_document
class BookDocument(Document):
    image = FileField()

    class Index:
        name = 'books'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0
        }

    class Django:
        model = Book

        fields = [
            'id',
            'title',
            'description',
        ]
```

but the images are not displayed on the search page, and since there is no ImageField field in django-elasticsearch-dsl, and only this file is suitable for storing file data, I do not know how to change this behavior
Perhaps someone has encountered such a problem and knows how to make it work

Comment: A `FileField`/`ImageField` is behind the curtains just a `CharField` that stores the *path* of the file.

Comment: That is, it is enough for me to simply set the CharField and write the path to the file?

Comment: @Dimapp: I think it might be sufficient to use a `CharField` in your document yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**`FileField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) is essentially jus a [**`CharField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#charfield) with some extra logic to wrap the data into a `FieldFile` that can then open, write, etc. on the file handler.

You thus can create a document with a `TextField` instead:

```
@registry.register_document
class BookDocument(Document):
    image = fields.TextField()

    class Index:
        name = 'books'
        settings = {'number_of_shards': 1, 'number_of_replicas': 0}

    class Django:
        model = Book

        fields = [
            'id',
            'title',
            'description',
        ]
```